# dplyr: test if every column is equal some value and output column(s) unequal

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that has an ID column and numeric columns. I want to test if every single numeric column equal a certain value, and if not, output the columns that don't equal that value.

```
> df
Source: local data frame [6 x 10]

     id    c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6    c7    c8    c9
  (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     4
2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
3     3     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
4     4     1     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
5     5     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
6     6     1     1     1     1     2     1     1     1     1
```

Is there a way to do it in dplyr? I can do it with filter by testing each column, but looking for a simple way.

```
library(dplyr)    
filter(df, c1 == 1, c2 == 1, c3 == 1, c4 == 1, c5 == 1, c6 == 1, c7 == 1, c8 == 1, c9 ==1)
```

I am looking for a solution that won't require me to enumerate each column name.

When I flip the conditions to finding rows that have at least one unequal (as follows), I still need to test each column to see which one is 'not equal' to specified value. Too cumbersome.

```
filter(df, c1 > 1 | c2 > 1 | c2 > 1
       | c4 > 1 | c5 > 1 | c6 > 1 | c7 > 1 | c8 > 1 | c9 > 1)
```

Comment: Why does it have to be "dplyr"? Why not just `which`?

Comment: I am a bit confused. It seems that you want to check if each column with numeric has an identical value (i.e., 1). If this is the case, I'd do `df[, sapply(df, function(x){any(x != 1)})]`. But, when I ran your `filter` code, you chose all rows containing `1`. I wonder if you meant row instead of column.

Comment: Yes, that is also a use case. It could be flipped to none of them being zero. I am looking for a solution that won't require me to enumerate each column name.

Comment: That is a very interesting solution. Had not thought of using sapply withing a subsetting case. Although, in my case, ID column will never be equal to a single value. So, this won't quite work.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by saying `Although, in my case, ID column will never be equal to a single value`? One more favor. Could you show all users your desired output? That will help us all.

Comment: Sorry, the column named 'ID' in my DF is a unique identifier per row. So, it will never be equal to a test value. Your 'sapply' subset solution picks up all rows with any column value not equal 1, including ID column. This ends up picking all rows in the DF.

Comment: Thanks for your update. The filter code now has a data frame we do not know. I am afraid I cannot run that. Could you revise that or update a new data frame? I want to clarify whether you want to check if each numeric column has `1` or each row has `1`. Which is it?

Comment: If your desire output is the one the 2nd filter generates, I'd do `df[rowSums(df[-1]) != ncol(df[-1]), ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your desired output is the one that 2nd filter code generates, I would do that following.

```
df[rowSums(df[-1]) != ncol(df[-1]), ]

#  id c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9
#1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  4
#4  4  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#6  6  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1
```

`rowSums(df[-1]) != ncol(df[-1])` generates a logical vector. For each row, you sum up numerics. Since your target value is `1`, if all columns have 1, the total should be equal to the number of column. Using this check, you subset rows by `df[rowSums(df[-1]) != ncol(df[-1]), ]`. I hope this is what you are after.